# Support for cancelling DHTML dialog box with escape

Tags: javascript, onkeydown

Imagine a DHTML dialog box with the following markup:

```
<div id="someDialog" class="dialog">
    <h2>Title of dialog</h2>

    Lots: <input ...>
    of: <select ...>
    controls: <textarea ...>

    <input type="submit" value="OK">
    <input type="reset" value="Cancel">
</div>
```

The user will expect hitting escape to cancel the dialog. This in itself isn't hard -- just add a keydown event handler to document.documentElement to check for ev.keyCode == 27, and use that to close the topmost dialog on the page.

The problem is this – there are certain circumstances where it's important that the browser sees the escape key first. For example, if the browser prompts with an autocomplete menu for `<input type="text">`, pressing escape should cancel that, not cancel the dialog. If you bring up the dropdown/popup menu for a `<select>`, pressing escape should close that, not the dialog.

How do you arrange to handle the escape key for a window, if and only if the browser doesn't need escape keypresses for something?

---

Edit: Stack Exchange itself has this very fault. If I click the "Would you like to have responses to your questions sent to you via email?" link, which opens a DHTML dialog box, then tab to the frequency dropdown, press alt-down to open the dropdown menu, then escape to close the dropdown menu, the whole dialog closes. This should not happen. The browser's control implementation should have first pickings on the escape key under these circumstances.

Comment: i'm workin on something for ya. When you focus on certain HTML elements, you need to register them as active, and when you hit escape, you need to see if any elements are 'active' if so, allow escape to behave natively, otherwise close the dialog

Answer (score 2):

After some decent researching and trial/error, the best/only solution here seems to be creating your own custom form controls.

---

The following is a failed attempt to solve the problem.

**http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/4jBgs/10/**

Here's basically how it works.

---

First, there's an `activeInput` variable which stores a `DOMElement` of the input that the user is focused on. (only if the input is escapable)

```
var activeInput = false;
```

---

In order to populate this variable, I created an array of the DOMElements that you mentioned can be `escaped` (textboxes with autocomplete, select elements)

```
var escapableElements = [];
escapableElements = escapableElements.concat(
    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('select')),
    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('input'))
    //add more elements here
);
```

and then looped through the array and attached `eventListeners` for the `focus` and `blur` (lose focus) events. (i included the for each function at the bottom of this post)

```
forEach(escapableElements, function() {
    this.addEventListener('focus', registerActiveElement);
    this.addEventListener('blur', deregisterActiveElement);
});

function registerActiveElement() {
    if (!activeInput)
        activeInput = this;
    //console.log('registered'); //testing only
}

function deregisterActiveElement() {
    if (activeInput)
        activeInput = false;
    //console.log('deregistered'); //testing only
}
```

---

After that, I wired up an `eventListener` for the `keydown` event. Inside of it, I checked to see if there is an `activeInput` if there is, I just `return true;` which will let the browser do what it wants (escape from autocomplete, etc) if there IS NOT an `activeInput`, I checked if `ESC` was pressed and call `hide_dialog_box(event.keyCode);`

The only difference from the paragraph in your question about handling the `ESC` keypress is that I checked to see if there was an `activeInput` beforehand. If there is an `activeInput`, I did nothing (let the browser handle ESC natively) if there's no `activeInput` I called `event.preventDefault()` which will cancel the browser's native handling of ESC and then called the function `hide_dialog_box(keyCode)` and then did `return false;` which also helps to prevent the browser from handling the `ESC` keypress.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (!activeInput) {
        if (event.keyCode == 27) { //esc
            event.preventDefault();
            hide_dialog_box(event.keyCode);
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return true; //if active input, let browser function
    }
    /*
        if the browser prompts with an autocomplete menu for 
        <input type="text">, or options on a <select> drop down
        pressing escape will cancel that, not cancel the dialog. 
    */
});
```

---

The last 2 snippits of code are the function `hide_dialog_box(keyCode)` and the function I wrote to wrote to loop through the `NodeList` called `escapableElements`

```
function hide_dialog_box(keyCode) {
    var dialog_box = document.getElementById('dialog_box');
        dialog_box.style.display = 'none';
}

function forEach(list, callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    {
        //calls the callback function, but places list[i] as the 'this'
        callback.call(list[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, two thoughts ... Firstly, my dialogs are generated dynamically (from AJAX, from manual construction) and controls can be added anywhere and at any time. I've considered code that hacks up every control on the page, but it just won't work, because any and every piece of code that ever adds a control, will break it.

Comment: (Grr, comment size limit)
———newpara———
Worse, your solution blocks escape **completely** within the given controls.
———newpara———
Here's a good example if you're in Windows. Open the Run dialog, and open the dropdown menu of recent commands, by typing, pressing alt-down, or clicking the dropdown button.
———newpara———
Press escape once: this dropdown list closes. Press escape a second time: the dialog closes. That is what I'm trying to achieve.
———newpara———
I don't want fragile code that relies on knowing what the browser _might_ do, I just want to let it do whatever it needs.

Comment: i modified the code a bit to take out the opening the dialog box because it was unnecessary. reading/processing your replies now

Comment: In order to handle the AJAX, you're going to have to create a function that unbinds the current escapableElements (check if they exist before unbinding), generates a NEW list of escapableElements and then binds those with the same eventHandlers. If you're open to using jQuery you could simplify this whole process by using `Delegates` and giving the escapable elements a specific classname, then event binding all elements with that class

Comment: going to rework the jsfiddle to try and fit your usecase a bit better and hopefully find something that works, ill check back here in a few

Comment: I create controls all over the place – I loathe anything that needs endless vigilance, instead of simply patching the single function that handles the escape key.———newpara———Granted, I don't honestly believe that there's a solution to this, and my experience with other sites is that DHTML dialog boxes aren't taken all that seriously, so I imagine no-one has ever noticed this issue before. There's no way I know to work out whether a control is in a state where the browser would like to accept escape keypresses, and who will ever know what those are? I can't say what all browsers do.

Comment: Okay, so in the situation that a user clicked a drop-down list and it's expanded. If they hit escape, it should close the drop-down list and if they hit escape again, it should close the dialog box... I'm not quite sure if it's POSSIBLE to know if the drop-down list has expanded or not...

Comment: You could create your own custom controls, just a bunch of div magic with hidden input elements off-screen. Sounds fun to me... :d

Comment: I don't expect the site to know or care how controls work at this level, I simply expect the browser to eat the escape keypress if it needs them.

Comment: I may have over-engineered this before event testing it. The browser seems to behave like you want in the fiddle i'm working with right now. ill post it in a sec

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/4jBgs/ check it out... It seems to behave how you wanted

Comment: only in chrome :[ you could hack it to work better in firefox, but you'd have to press ESC twice instead.. which would be dumb

Comment: I think the only sure-fire solution here is to create your own form controls... :/